# C# MVC Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Types

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I could not find my exact problem, so I have posted this question, if there is already a correct answer for this please do link it.

I am receiving an error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Types

On my C# MVC application. This error is about a version which is not being used on a dll anymore, 10.0.0.0 instead of 12.0.0.0.

This error only occurs when I publish my project to IIS on a specific server and not on a local machine nor any other servers, in fact if I publish it to a different server it works perfectly.

I have checked GAC and cannot see any problems, I have removed temporary ASP.NET files and I have crawled through every possible file using notepad++ search files*.* For the public key reference of the dll to find it and still I cannot find where the old reference is pointing from.

The dll is merged into another using ILMerge but this has not been a problem before now, just on this project and only on this server, i have even used dotnet peek to ensure the merged dll has the correct version 12.0.0.0 in it and it does.

It almost feels like its cached on the server somehow but I cannot figure out where, is there anything else I have not done that someone can recommended in terms of clearing some form of cached reference or something on the IIS server with the problem?

Comment: Does your web.config have an older binding value in the assemblies section?

Comment: unfortunatly not, to be honest the web config does not have the binding in at all as it was a direct reference added to the project via dll not a nuget package

Comment: Do you have nested projects and therefore, multiple web.configs?

Answer (score 0):

It's probably looking for one of its dependencies if you'r sure the dll is in the bin folder.

Instead of referencing from the GAC have you tried removing the reference and adding the following NuGet package ?

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SqlServer.Types/